# Retain htl and body tags in HTML parser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery html parser($.parseHTML()).
The problem with this function is that , if i pass a string that contain html body and form tags,the function returns only form tag.
But i want to retain the original tags as well.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: `$.parseHTML()` uses the browser's built-in HTML parser, by assigning to `temporaryelement.innerHTML`. If the browser discards these tags, jQuery can't get them back.

Comment: is there any other way to retain them?

Comment: say that i place the entire html in a text area and then i parse it,using the $.parseHTML().Now the html and body tags of the content in textarea are stripped.i want to retain that html and body tags in the text area...how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = document.createElement('html');
a.innerHTML = '<head></head><body><form></form></body>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

```
$(function () {
  var htmlstr = "<html data-abc=123><body>abc<form><input type=text /></form>"
                  + "</body></html>";
  var d = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
  d.write(htmlstr);
  var _html = $(d).find("html");
  $("textarea").val(_html[0].outerHTML)
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ecf6gjxo/

Comment: d.write(html) ---> d.write(htmlstr) ?